# Tensor multiplication in tensorflow (with indetermined number of axes)

Tags: python, tensorflow, linear-algebra, numpy-einsum

I have a tensor `a` with an unknown number of axes (but at least one) and a square matrix `M` such that `a.get_shape()[0] == M.get_shape()[0]==M.get_shape()[1]`.

What I would like to do is

```
R = tf.einsum("i...,ij->j...",a,M)
```

but unlike the numpy `einsum`, the tensorflow `einsum` which has recently been implemented in version 11 of tensorflow does support using `...`, so I could solve my problem if I knew for example that `a` had rank 4, then I could do

```
R = tf.einsum("imkl,ij->jmkl",a,M)
```

But what do I do when the rank of `a` is unknown? Is there some sort of efficient work-arround?

Comment: `R = tf.einsum("imkl,ij->jmkl",a,M)` should work. If you add this in the unit test, then it returns sucessfully. Perhaps you have an older version?

Comment: Also, for ellipsis, please follow the [github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5443).

Comment: @drpng thanks. I know `R = tf.einsum("imkl,ij->jmkl",a,M)` works. What I mean is that I can use that if I know `a` is a rank 4 tensor, but if I don't know the rank of `a` then I don't know what to do.

Comment: Oh, I see. How about `get_shape().ndims?`?